# Can not post json data using angularjs to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I simply want to post the data my data which is JSON object but I can not. the post via firebug shows that I am actually posting json data to server d, but when debugging the controller my d is null.

```
  $scope.update = function() {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'EditData',
            data: {d: $scope.myData},
        }).success(function() {
            alert(data.msg);
        });
    };
```

I did try to JSON.parse myData that didn't work either.

Here is my controller:

```
public JsonResult EditData(string d)
```

I am not sure what I am doing right here. probably something silly. :(

Comment: Shouldn't your URL be something like: `Controller/Action`, ex: `/notes/edit`?

Comment: Remove the comma after your data Object. `myData},`. Also check your network request headers to make sure the correct data is being passed, if it is, it's probably a webconfig issue in your solution.

Comment: @NewDev that is going to Home/EditData double checked it.

Comment: Well... another thing to check would be that you have `[HttpPost]` attribute declared on your `EditData` method

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall removed the , still the same. still looking.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you make the request? Is the Json MIME type in your web config?

Comment: Paste your complete controller class please ?

Comment: @Pracede I don't think this has anything to do with controller content.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I was able to JSON.stringify and it worked. I believe it was still treating my json as an object.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper Awesome, glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. JSON.stringify();

```
 $scope.update = function() {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: 'EditData',
                data: {d: JSON.stringify($scope.myData)},
            }).success(function() {
                alert(data.msg);
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$scope.update = function() {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'EditData',
        data: $scope.myData,
    }).success(function() {
        alert(data.msg);
    });
};
```